# Does same material with different colour will ended up in same temperature if both of them receive same thermal radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

"Every good heat radiation absorbent is a good emitter."

Suppose I have two identical material with different colour, placed in different room, receiving same and only thermal radiation.

My question is, **will both material will ended up in same temperature**, since at steady state the amount of energy absorbed and emitted is equal (but both material have different number of emitted and absorbed energy per unit time)? In simple word, does it mean that every same material with different colour have same final temperature (in ideal heat transfer state, only radiation is counted, in final steady state)? If not, what is the explanation, since it seems that black roof ended up hotter than the white one.

Comment: somewhat related [Emissivity and Final Temperature of a Black and White object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245949/83380)